# Evolution has lost all email data after upgrade to 11.04, is there a way to recover the data?

Tags: evolution, email, user-data

Evolution seems to have deleted all my emails after an upgrade to natty, is there a way I can recover this data? Is there some mystical folder somewhere that stores this data or should I just forgive and forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did before upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04 was first make a backup using Evolution and when the backup was complete i also made a copy of my .evolution folder in my home directory. After the upgrade i restored the Evolution backup and and copied the .evolution folder into my 11.04 home directory and all my data (including my sent mail and other folders i made and stuff i saved) was ready to use. But once you upgraded your Ubuntu all the old data will be removed... so consider it gone.

Comment: It's strange 'coz I upgraded to 10.10 something like two weeks ago and everything was fine no lost data with any applications.  Bugger I had some stuff I needed there oh well.....

Comment: A tip for next time is to leave the mail on the server. That is especially helpful if you switch from pop3-mail-protocol to imap. Most providers support imap-login and they usually have more professional backup-methods than you could dream of. Also it's a huge advantage if you want to synchronize mail between different clients (handy, work pc, private pc) as imap does that automatically.